# jquery + css scroll above div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm following this forum for a longer time. But because I didn't find an answer, I've registered to ask a question.

So my HTML structure is following:

```
<div id="nav">
...<!-- navigation #1 !-->
</div>

<div id="nav2">
<li><a id="jan" href="#januar">JANUAR</a></li>
etc..
<!-- navigation #1 !-->
</div>


<div id="content">
<div id="januar">
*header here*
*table here*
</div>
<!-- februar, etc...-->
</div>
```

Now what I want is. When clicking the `#jan` link, navigate the `#januar` to the middle of the screen, however DON'T scroll OVER the nav and nav2. I've tried many css and jquery tricks. But none work.
I also didn't found any theme with such criterias. Any suggestions?

Comment: In valid html code li (list item) must be inside ul OR ol, not in div

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achive and how? if you want to scroll the page to `#januar` then you need to scroll over the `#nav` and `#nav2`. Really don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script adjust top value to 50%.. to make it middle

```
 $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#januar').first().offset().top - 100
                }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery animate function, here is link for how to use `http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/`